# Can't make number negative

Tags: swift, random, casting, floating-point, negative-number

I have this `swift` code:

```
x = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
y = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
z = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
coords.x = 0.00 - x
coords.y = 0.00 - y
coords.z = 0.00 - z

print("\(coords.x)       \(coords.y)         \(coords.z)      xyz")
```

For some reason it always outputs the numbers as positive, I have also tried:

```
x = -Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
y = -Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
z = -Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
coords.x = x
coords.y = y
coords.z = z
```

and...

```
x = -1 * Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
y = -1 * Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
z = -1 * Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
coords.x = x
coords.y = y
coords.z = z
```

...and even one more where I had to cast the random number as an Int to multiply it by -1 within the `Float` cast.

```
x = Float(-1*Int(arc4random_uniform(30)))
...
```

The console output is always something like:

```
24.0       27.0         29.0      xyz
```

...no negative numbers.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

`coords` is of type `MyDict` which I created:

```
class MyDict : NSDictionary {
    var x: Float = 0.0
    var y: Float = 0.0
    var z: Float = 0.0
}
```

This is how I am printing the values:

```
print("\(coords.x)       \(coords.y)         \(coords.z)      xyz")
```

**EDIT**

`MyDict` is now:

```
struct Coords {
    var x: Float = 0.0
    var y: Float = 0.0
    var z: Float = 0.0
}
```

**EDIT**

Code for context - this is happening in a loop:

```
for nodeInnermost in nodeInner.childNodes {
                    if (nodeInnermost.name?.localizedStandardContains("ship"))! {
                        print(nodeInnermost.childNodes.first ?? "FIRST DOESNT EXIST")
                        var seqArray = [fadeOut, fadeIn]
                        var displacements = [] as Array<Coords>

                        var count = 0
                        var coords = Coords()

                        while count < 5 {
                            if childCount < 5 {
                                coords.x = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                                coords.y = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                                coords.z = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                            }
                            else if childCount > 4 && childCount < 10 {
                                coords.x = -Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                                coords.y = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                                coords.z = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                            }
                            else if childCount > 9 && childCount < 15 {
                                coords.x = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                                coords.y = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                                coords.z = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                            }
                            else if childCount > 14 && childCount < 20 {
                                coords.x = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                                coords.y = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                                coords.z = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                            }
                            else if childCount > 19 && childCount < 25 {
                                coords.x = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                                coords.y = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                                coords.z = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                            }
                            else if childCount > 24 && childCount < 30 {
                                coords.x = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                                coords.y = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                                coords.z = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                            }
                            else if childCount > 29 && childCount < 35 {
                                coords.x = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                                coords.y = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                                coords.z = Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                            }
                            else if childCount > 34 && childCount < 40 {
                                coords.x = -Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                                coords.y = -Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                                coords.z = -Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
                            }

                            //print("\(x)       \(y)         \(z)      xyz")
                            displacements.append(coords)

                            print("\(coords.x)       \(coords.y)         \(coords.z)      xyz")

                            let moveBy = SCNAction.move(by: SCNVector3Make(coords.x, coords.y, coords.z), duration: 0.5)

                            seqArray.append(fadeOut)
                            seqArray.append(moveBy)
                            seqArray.append(fadeIn)

                            count+=1
                        }

                        while count < 10 {
                            let moveBy = SCNAction.move(by: SCNVector3Make(displacements[9 - count].x, displacements[9 - count].y, displacements[9 - count].z), duration: 0.5)

                            seqArray.append(fadeOut)
                            seqArray.append(moveBy)
                            seqArray.append(fadeIn)

                            count+=1
                        }

                        let sequence = SCNAction.sequence(seqArray)
                        let animation = SCNAction.repeatForever(sequence)

                        nodeInnermost.childNodes.first?.runAction(animation)
                    }
                }
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

https://pastebin.com/Ak1pb6wP

Comment: What is coords? How are you printing the values?

Comment: editing my post

Comment: ok i edited it.

Comment: Why is MyDict a class and why does it extend NSDictionary.

Comment: just how i am handling the data....does it matter for my problem? i am storing the coords object in an array so i can reference it and get the x,y,z

Comment: MyDict (poorly named) should be a simple struct with three properties.

Comment: lol yah right as u commented i realized it should just be NSObject...im not sure if that will change the negative number problem ill see

Comment: No, it should not extend NSObject.

Comment: how should it go then? and why would this matter for the negative numbers?

Comment: check my edit..i think that is right

Comment: Looking at your latest code, why do you expect any negative numbers? Your `while` loop only runs when `count < 5` and in that condition you only create positive numbers.

Comment: i forgot to put   back in most of the negatives..it worked thanks...and thanks for struct lesson :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes no sense for your `MyDict` to extend `NSDictionary` nor should it be a `class`. Once you make it a proper `struct`, your code works fine.

```
struct MyDict {
    var x: Float = 0.0
    var y: Float = 0.0
    var z: Float = 0.0
}

var coords = MyDict()
coords.x = -Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
coords.y = -Float(arc4random_uniform(30))
coords.z = -Float(arc4random_uniform(30))

print("\(coords.x)       \(coords.y)         \(coords.z)      xyz")
```

Output:

```
-24.0       -28.0         -4.0      xyz
```

Comment: i still got all positives...let me post all of my code

Comment: Copy and paste the code from my answer into a playground. Do you still get positive numbers using my exact code? If so, what version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: let me see...ive never used playground before

Comment: it works in playground i am using Xcode Version 9.3 beta (9Q98q)

Comment: nm i got it...ur code worked...i forgot to put in the `-` signs before I ran for most of them so I didnt see any negative numbers....thanks